# Cannot print correct predictions using tensor flow

Tags: python, tensorflow, softmax

I've implemented a logistic regression that works fine. It prints out the accuracy correctly. I display the accuracy as so...

```
# Test model
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(pred, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
# Calculate accuracy
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

print("Accuracy:", accuracy.eval({x: mnist.test.images, y: mnist.test.labels}))
```

As I said, this works fine. However, after reading a tutorial, I know that `correct_prediction` should be an array of booleans that tells us whether our predictions are true. I want to print this boolean value but I run into issues. I tried the following...

```
print(correct_prediction)
>>>Tensor("Equal:0", shape=(?,), dtype=bool)
```

and then I tried...

```
print(sess.run(correct_prediction))
>>>InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder' with dtype float
 [[Node: Placeholder = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
```

I am quite new to TensorFlow. How can I print out this variable as an array of predictions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still need to feed in the data. Try:

```
print(correct_prediction.eval({x: mnist.test.images, y: mnist.test.labels}))
```